# 7zip batch multiple files in directory without folder in archive

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a series of file in a series of folders that need to be zipped individually.

```
C:\folder1\file1-1.txt
C:\folder1\file1-2.txt
C:\folder1\file1-3.txt

C:\folder2\file2-1.txt
C:\folder2\file2-2.txt
C:\folder2\file2-3.txt
C:\folder2\file2-4.txt

C:\folder3\file3-1.txt
C:\folder3\file3-2.txt
C:\folder3\file3-3.txt
C:\folder3\file3-4.txt
C:\folder3\file3-5.txt
```

I usee the below code to zip each folder, no problem:

```
for /d %%X in (fol*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%cd%\ZIPS\%%X.zip" "%%X"
```

And I'm left with 3 zip files in a directory "ZIPS" with the contents of each folder in their own ZIP, as is desired.

```
C:\ZIPS\folder1.zip
C:\ZIPS\folder2.zip
C:\ZIPS\folder3.zip
```

However within each file, I'm left with the folder as well as the files.

```
e.g. C:\ZIPS\folder1.zip\folder1\<files here>
```

What I'm after is the files being saved in the root of the directory:

```
e.g. C:\ZIPS\folder1.zip\<files here>
```

I've tried removing the "%%X" at the end of the line, however all that does is save all files in all directories for each folder.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the folder where the files to compress are stored

```dos
for /d %%X in (fol*) do ( 
    pushd "%%~fX" & (
        "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%cd%\ZIPS\%%~nX.zip" *
        popd
    )
)
```